# How to split up React Native src application into multiple applications?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I'm currently developing a mobile application (on React Native) for an existing web application (frontend built on Vue JS).

In web application I have multiple user offices (anonymous user can only login, change site language, and access other primitive features; admin has an office, where he can manage users, make bookings, invoices etc; customer has an access to features that belong only to that user type), and in Vue JS its divided not only on `src`, but `src-anonymous`, `src-admin`, `src-customer`.

It also contains `vue.config.js` file, where I set how many pages my application has. Also web application uses webpack for that purposes.

So how to make this offices split in React Native application for anon, admin and customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a column in users table such as : user_type and set values i.e.

user_type 0 for Guest,
user_type  1 for Admin,
user_type 2  for Customer,

in database.

then on React-Native after fetching response , you can check with condition and navigate to respective Pages.

```
if(response.user_type === 0) {
   this.props.navigation("GuestView");
} else if(response.user_type ===1) {
   this.props.navigation.navigate("AdminView")
}
```

Another way is you can create Components for Specific things,such as a Booking Component which will visible to admin. then render them conditionally

```
{ this.props.user_type === 1 && 

<Bookings />

}
```

with above condition Bookings Component will only be visible to Admin.

Comment: Is that good pattern to mix all of these components for different offices just in one `src` entry folder?

Comment: you can create subfolders in src, such admin, customer, and create specific components there, and then import them. both of the above methods can done, either you can create totally separate views or create small components and then render them based on condition, bold are valid ways to do.

Comment: Yep, I also thought about that last night, I already have user types, just wanted to be sure its a good approach to mix it all under 1 src folder